# Not all Vim Text Transparent

Tags: vim, vimrc

I am using the following commands after setting the color scheme to make my `vim` transparent:

```
highlight Normal ctermbg=none
highlight NonText ctermbg=none
highlight SpecialKey ctermbg=none
```

However, when editing `tex`(latex) files (with the [`vimtex`](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex) plugin installed) I still get a background for some tokens:

[image: vim]

As you can see for example the token `12pt` or `\date` has a background. What else do I need to add to remove this background?

Comment: Would be better asked on http://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Bichoy Didn't know it existed. Next time I'll definitely ask it there. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

It appears `vimtex` adds its own custom highlighting. I turned off the background for these:

```
highlight texMathMatcher ctermbg=none
highlight texMathZoneX ctermbg=none
highlight texRefLabel ctermbg=none
highlight texStatement ctermbg=none
```

Feel free to let me know if there is a more elegant solution.